# Why running a php code and manipulating the DB is much faster from the server than using the browser?

Tags: php, performance, server, ubuntu-server

I have a web app that get information from an external API, and adds them to the DB and sends an email if there is something wrong with one of the variables.

This was activated manually on the browser every day I come to the office, which got me waiting when running the URL (activates a function/controller that does all that, using CodeIgniter MVC Framework). Whenever I am waiting for the controller to run, I couldn't get to my web-app URL until this is done (I get the loading icon in every URL that includes my website - but only on my PC, on other PCs that were connected to the server were able to view the web-app normally.

1. Why Does this happen and what is the right way to prevent that?

For the first time today - I used "cronjob" (Ubuntu Server) - running it automatically everyday, instead of me doing that from the browser every day manually.

It did everything **EXTREMELY** fast. (seriously, shocking-speed-fast)

2. How and why did it do it SO fast?

What should I research on google?

Is there a way to use this "force" of running things on the server itself and less from a PHP code, but from the PHP code?

Comment: For your first question, see the duplicate. For the second, we can't say a whole lot about that without more information and the actual timings involved.

Comment: Where do you think the PHP code is running? Do you really somehow believe that it runs in the browser?

Comment: @MarkBaker no, but I am asking is why is there a difference with running it on the browser that running it on the server

Comment: Accessing a script through the browser.... overhead of dns lookup, http request, webserver handling, network latency, etc